# Only first row button is working in a table

Tags: javascript, php, html

Problem: In the complete column, there is yes button after clicking on it, it show consulted but problem is only one row is working. I don't understand how i defined each row uniquely. Please have a look at this code and let me know what mistake I'm  doing here.

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive ">
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM book_now";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
        <table class="table table-bordered table table-striped" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0">
            <thead class="table table-success text-center" style="width: 80%">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 1%"> S.No </th>
                    <th> Patient Name </th>
                    <th> UHID </th>
                    <th style="width: 12%"> Time Slot </th>
                    <th> Contact No </th>
                    <th> Complete </th>
                    <th> Write Prescription </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)        
{
    foreach($query_run as $row)
    {
?>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <td><?php  echo $row['booking_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $row['booked_by']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $row['appointment_time_slot']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <input onclick="func()" id="accountDetails" type="button" value="Yes"></input>
<script>
function func() {
    document.getElementById('accountDetails').value  = 'Consulted';
}
</script>
                        </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "working"? How is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `id` attributes in the repeated content which creates duplicates. `id` have to be unique.

To fix the issue change that `id` to a `class`, then you can create an event handler to listen for any click on any of the `button` elements. From there you can use the Event object passed to the event handler to update *only* the button which was clicked.

Note in the example below the use of an unobtrusive event handler instead of an inline `onclick` attribute. The latter is not good practice and should be avoided. Also note that the event is delegated to the parent `table`. This allows us to use a *single* event handler no matter how many rows/buttons the table contains, or if they are dynamically created after the DOM loads.

```js
document.querySelector('#dataTable').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.accountDetails'))  
    e.target.value = 'Consulted';
});
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="table-responsive ">
    <table class="table table-bordered table table-striped" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0">
      <thead class="table table-success text-center" style="width: 80%">
        <tr
          <th> Complete </th>
          <th> Write Prescription </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <input class="accountDetails" type="button" value="Yes" />
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <input class="accountDetails" type="button" value="Yes" />
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>        
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <input class="accountDetails" type="button" value="Yes" />
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have make the form have same id `accountDetails` and then you select by the same id,so it's only work for first row

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input onclick="func()" id="accountDetails" type="button" value="Yes"></input>
    <script>
    function func() {
    document.getElementById('accountDetails').value  = 'Consulted';
    }
    </script>
</form>
```

In order to solve it,you need to make id unique in each row,below is one option for you

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input onclick="func()" id="accountDetails<?php  echo $row['booking_id']; ?>" type="button" value="Yes"></input>
    <script>
    function func() {
    document.getElementById('accountDetails<?php  echo $row['booking_id']; ?>').value  = 'Consulted';
    }
    </script>
</form>
```